# Save Channels in PS separately

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to save channels in PS separately with transparent whites like in this picture – resp. Does anyone know how this is done if not with separated channels?

[image: Literata by Javier Zamora]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can save your Photoshop file included the main CMYK or RGB channels and you may export one channel separately by switching off all channels that you don't want and export the visible result to a separated file.

also you can do the same effect with any colors you want (not the main CMYK or RGB) by using the "Duotones" mode.

for converting a full color image to a duotone one please do the following.

1. Convert the image to grayscale by choosing Image > Mode > Grayscale. Only 8‑bit grayscale images can be converted to duotones.
2. Choose Image > Mode > Duotone.
3. In the Duotone Options dialog box, select Preview to preview the image.
4. For the Type option, select Monotone, Duotone, Tritone, or Quadtone.
5. Click the color box (the solid square) to open the color picker, then click the Color Libraries button and select an ink book and color from the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else is looking for the same: After I followed hsawires's steps, I managed to get the whites transparent by doing the following things:

1. Select all (Cmd+a), copy (Cmd+c)
2. Go to the Channels-Panel, create a new Alpha Channel Paste the picture (Cmd+v), Invert it (Cmd+i)
3. Go back to the Layer-Panel, Select > Load Selection > Choose your new created Alpha-Channel
4. All white areas should be selected and you can just add a new Layer Mask

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it manually.

1. Make MODE > CMYK.
2. Flatten the image and go to channels.
3. Click the icon right above and click split channels
   (it will now create 4 grayscale CMYK windows).
4. You may go with the 1st window, the CYAN. Convert it to MODE > CMYK.
5. Go to LAYERS. Create a new fill layer with CYAN color on top and click the blending mode to SCREEN.
6. Do the same with the rest (MYK).